# Corda node explorer for custom cordapps

Tags: corda

Is it possible to use corda `node-explorer` for cordapps other than `cash`? Is there any open source project to visualise what's going on in the blockchain for my cordapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node Explorer currently only works for the cash CorDapp.

I don't know of any other open source projects to visualise activity on Corda.

However, it would make for a great project to extend Node Explorer to include other CorDapps, the source is available here https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/tools

Comment: So, https://docs.corda.net/testnet-explorer-corda.html this won't work with custom dapp, right?

Comment: You'll be able to spin up nodes running your custom CorDapp and use explorer to view the network and view transactions, but you won't be able to interact with your app from explorer.

Comment: After developing one project on Corda, I feel that there is too much outdated stuff in the documentation. Also, if we generate nodes on test network, they are shipped with v3.3, while the latest version is 4.x. There is too much confusion about node config and deployment. I also don't understand why I have to write certain kind of code for flows in order to implement certain things. Docs are more like explaining rocket science, thanks to the videos. Is the framework already messed up? I don't think anyone can enjoy writing code with this mess. Hope you guys fix these issues soon.

Answer (score 0):

It is a long back question, but still want to update since someone may need this.

A Beta Release for Node-Explorer was released recently, whose key highlight is:

> **Node Explorer is able to point to your own CorDapps.**

More details in here:

```
https://github.com/corda/node-explorer/releases
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cn2lhS8pjRs
```